# How could I define what function is more efficient for comparing arrays with custom models

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, compare

I wrote two functions to compare arrays. Now I am struggling how to compare these approaches and find out what is the most suitable.

I would like to know how could I evaluate each function that I wrote.

**By equal I understand that all elements of arrays are same.**

**By evaluate I am asking performance (Time and Complexity) and usage of Swift features.**

My structure that is used in arrays:

```
struct Wallet {
    var fund = 0
    var name = ""

    public static func ==(lhs: Wallet, rhs: Wallet) -> Bool{
        return lhs.fund == rhs.fund && lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    public static func !=(lhs: Wallet, rhs: Wallet) -> Bool{
        return lhs.fund != rhs.fund || lhs.name != rhs.name
    }
}
```

First approach with usage of the `zip`:

```
func compare(x: Array<Wallet>, y: Array<Wallet>) -> Bool {
    let state = zip(x, y).enumerated().filter() {
        $1.0 == $1.1
        }.count == x.count
    return state
}
```

Second approach when I sort array and than compare.

```
func compare(x: Array<Wallet>, y: Array<Wallet>) -> Bool {

    if x.count != y.count {
        return false
    }

    let xSorted = x.sorted{$0.fund > $1.fund}
    let ySorted = y.sorted{$0.fund > $1.fund}

    for (pos, xItem) in xSorted.enumerated() {
        let yItem = ySorted[pos]
        if xItem != yItem {
            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: As for time, create an array of some large size ~10^6, and compare the timings between the two functions. Try it on various arrays and find the average.

Comment: The second function sorts the arrays before comparing them element-wise, which the first function doesn't. So they do not the same. – In both functions, the use of `enumerated()` seems unnecessary.

Comment: If you make Wallet Equatable then you can simply compare the arrays with `==`, no extra code needed.

Comment: @MartinR you are right thx for the suggestion.  Could you please post suggestion as answer because it reasonable improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions are not optimal:

- Calling `enumerated()` is unnecessary because the index position is
  not used in the closure.
- Both solutions do not short-circuit: They compare all array elements
  even if a different pair is found.

`contains()` does short-circuit, so this would be a better solution:

```
func compare(x: Array<Wallet>, y: Array<Wallet>) -> Bool {
    return x.count == y.count &&
        !zip(x, y).contains { $0 != $1 }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
func compare(x: Array<Wallet>, y: Array<Wallet>) -> Bool {
    return x.elementsEqual(y, by: ==)
}
```

But you get that for free if you make the type `Equatable` (note
that you don't have to implement `!=`, that is provided automatically:

```
struct Wallet: Equatable {
    var fund = 0
    var name = ""

    public static func ==(lhs: Wallet, rhs: Wallet) -> Bool{
        return lhs.fund == rhs.fund && lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

Now you can compare arrays simply with `==`, using the existing

```
func ==<Element>(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Array<Element>) -> Bool
 where Element : Equatable
```

operator.

Comment: I'm sorry, that I'm typing it here. But I realy need expert reply. Can you, please, check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695641/uiimageview-or-avplayer-photo-or-video-in-uitableviewcell
I will delete this comment after it. Sorry one more time