# UIImageView or AVPlayer (photo or video) in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-storage

**1)** I have an application with `UITableView`. This cell has some content like `UILabel`, `UIButton` (likes, description, etc.) and it also should store image or video (depends on type of post (like `instagram` classic post)). So cells can be one of the 2 types: with video or with photo. Other info, constraints, sizes etc. are similar.

At the moment I have only one custom cell type with `UIView` (both for photo/video). And I'm adding layers of `AVPlayer` and `UIImageView` on this `UIView`. It works, but I think it is a bad way of how this can be done. Also It's pretty bad logic with layers.

How to do it properly? Should I have 2 custom cell types? Or maybe some library exists for it?

**2)** I'm downloading data from `Firebase-storage`. This operations are async. So I'm storing `MediaAspectRatio` of media (`width/height`) in my `PostItem`. I'm using it to scale `UIView` before cell appears to not crop media. I'm also not sure, that it is correct logic.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 1.) I'm not sure if it is better, but I am using two different custom cells for that.

Comment: @MarcelT I see. I want to have common solution for it. Thanks for your reply. Also, are you downloading your media async? How do u resize your views to not crop it?

Comment: Sorry but I cant answer your firebase related question, cause I am using the Photos Framework in my App. Also, I'am cropping it, so I cant help you with that either sorry.

Comment: @MarcelT anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways will work. However having 2 different cell types might be a cleaner implementation.

Also having 2 cell types will save you from having to swap the imageView with the AvPlayer layers on the fly, which might complicate things because of cell reuse.

As for the resizing you do, just make sure you don't break any constraints, the logic sounds good.

Image views and AvPlayers have the notion of AspectFill, that is what you want to do to not break the aspect ration of your media and not crop it at the same time.

AspectFit on the other hand will keep the Aspect Ratio and crop.

Comment: Thanks you for reply. My upvote for u. Maybe will accept soon

Comment: Thanks @VladPulichev